# How can I use Maven to get the latest Hibernate release?

Tags: hibernate, maven-2, dependencies, pom.xml

I am having trouble getting the latest release of Hibernate via Maven dependency.  It appears that the latest I can fetch from a Maven central repository is 3.2.6.GA, and I am interested in using 3.3.2.GA, which is the latest release shown on the hibernate.org site.  When I modify my hibernate dependency to this latest version in my project's pom.xml I get the following error when I run a Maven build:

```
Missing:
----------
1) org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.3.2.GA

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command:
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.hibernate -DartifactId=hibernate -D
version=3.3.2.GA -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:

      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.hibernate -DartifactId=hibernate -Dve
rsion=3.3.2.GA -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[
id]
```

Once I do that I continue to get errors indicating that I need to add a javassist dependency, then I need to update my hibernate-validator dependency, which also needs to be installed locally, and at that point I stopped and looked around to see if there is a better way, maybe pointing Maven to a JBoss/Hibernate repository, etc.  This really seems to be a headache compared to other significant open cource packages that I use such as Spring or JUnit -- when there's a new version released all I do is update the version number in the dependency element and it just works.

I have tried adding the below repository declaration into my pom.xml but with no joy:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jboss</id>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

I searched Google and didn't find much which helps.  Can someone suggest the most straight-forward way of going about using the latest releases of hibernate or hibernate-core (3.3.2.GA), hibernate-validator (3.1.0), and hibernate-annotations (3.4.0)?

Comment: Please see my answer below: this question is strongly outdated, as most other upvoted answers.

Answer (score 36):

JBoss have started synchronising their own repo with Maven central as [posted on the JBoss community blog](http://community.jboss.org/en/build/blog/2011/05/24/rsync-jbossorg-to-maven-central) , therefore `hibernate` artifacts are now available without the need to add the JBoss repository to your `pom.xml` or repository manager.

[Search result for hibernate-core](http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22org.hibernate%22%20AND%20a%3A%22hibernate-core%22):

[image: search result for hibernate-core]

To add the Hibernate Core 3.6.3 to your project, just add the following snippet to your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 17):

You're having problems because org.hibernate:hibernate:3.3.2.GA is an aggregator POM used to build the rest of the modules, it isn't actually a jar. It looks like a refactoring happened after 3.2.7 and that's thrown people off. For reference this [blog entry](http://blog.hibernate.org/Bloggers/HibernateCore332MaintenanceRelease#comment11899) hints at problems they've had promoting Hibernate to central and may explain the change.

If you look in the [JBoss repository](http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/hibernate/), you'll see that the hibernate modules for 3.3.2.GA *are* hosted, they're just hosted as individual artifacts, hibernate-core, hibernate-ehcache etc. So your repository declaration is correct, you just need to fine tune the dependency declarations to take the change into account.

The JBoss repository hosts [hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.GA](http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-annotations/3.4.0.GA/), [hibernate-validator-3.1.0.GA](http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/3.1.0.GA/), and [hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA](http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/3.3.2.GA/) amongst others. Try adding the specific artifacts to your POM and use the JBoss repository as you've already declared.

There is also a [hibernate-dependencies](http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-distribution/3.3.2.GA/) pom that provides transitive dependencies to the majority of hibernate artifacts (including core). So the simplest thing to do would be to replace your existing *hibernate* dependency declaration with *hibernate-dependencies*

Your dependencies would end up like this...

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-dependencies <!--or hibernate-core--></artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <!--hibernate-dependencies is a pom, not needed for hibernate-core-->
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
  </dependency>
  ...
  <!--any other hibernate deps not inherited transitively-->
```

To make your life simpler you could define all these hibernate dependencies in a project say called (hibernate-all), then reference that single project for all your projects that use hibernate (of course it would be nice if the hibernte team provided that project anyway).

Comment: Wonder why I'm seeing errors like the below when I run my build after adding the repository and dependencies above?

    [INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.hibernate:hibernate-dependencies:jar:3.3.2.GA' in repository jboss (http://repository.jboss.org/maven2)

Comment: hibernate-dependencies is a pom project, so you need to set <type>pom</type> on the dependency declaration, alternatively use hibernate-core

Comment: @Rich: I have the same issue, and no, setting `<type>pom</type>` doesn't help

Comment: @Rich, I had the same problem and could not work out why the dependency hibernate:3.2.5.ga worked but 3.3.2.GA would fail. I could see the difference in the two in search.maven.org but you still need to specify the dependency as <type>pom</type> to make it work. Good answer and seems to me to be the correct answer, although must admit I didn't pick up the type attribute on the first 10 readings.

Answer (score 4):

It's frustrating, but the newer versions just aren't there, and haven't been for a long time. The irony is that the Hibernate artifacts have some fairly intricate inter-dependencies and well-documented minimum versions of those dependencies, which would be ideally represented as a Maven POM. Instead, we have to download the binaries ourselves and try and express them locally.

Answer (score 2):

You can use dependance in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.ga</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

This question is outdated since a long time now:
all Hibernate releases are available in Maven central since years.

Check www.hibernate.org for latest Maven coordinates (do not trust your IDE's suggestions).

Answer (score 0):

the jars are missing in the repository, maybe that is the reason the latest hibernate version is not in the main repoistory

Comment: I can see the jars in the repository: 
<p>
http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/3.3.2.GA/hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar
<p>
http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/3.1.0.GA/hibernate-validator-3.1.0.GA-sources.jar
<p>
http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-annotations/3.4.0.GA/hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.GA.jar

Comment: that explains a little. apparently hibernate is renamed to hibernate-core and the jars are put there. but the don't follow the naming convention, so there are not usable with maven...

Answer (score 0):

new to this and playing around with it.  I don't have a complete solution BUT:

> It seemed like I  was able to resolve a few dependencies by including http://repository.jboss.com/maven3/ instead of maven 2.

for those that remain problematic, one can as a last straw download the missing files from the maven site, for example, browse:

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/3.6.8.Final/

(yes, i tried setting this and other reasonable paths as a repository source, but without success...)

to install this jar into your maven build, do something like:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=path/to/jar/hibernate-core-3.6.8.Final.jar -DgroupId=org.hibernate -DartifactId=hibernate-core -Dversion=3.6.8-Final -Dpackaging=jar
```

reference:http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

sorry, just realized some of this is redundant, but hope it's helpful to some to see the additional possible URLs.  - JB