# POM dependencies not working (Eclipse, Maven, POM)

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, maven-2, pom.xml

I have a project in Eclipse (Helios), with Maven pom.xml.
My project is a web app that will use Hibernate, MySQL.

But i have endless woes in getting pom.xml right. I am new to maven, and can't believe setting up dependencies is so tough(do others have similar expierience / or am i dumb).

My pom.xml is here:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MyProj1</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyProj1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
      <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
      <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
      <layout>default</layout> 
      <releases> 
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </snapshots> 
    </repository>

    <repository>
      <id>Scala Tools</id>
      <name>Scala Tools</name>
      <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/</url>
      <layout>default</layout> 
      <releases> 
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </snapshots> 
    </repository>

  </repositories> 

  <dependencies> 

    <dependency> 
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> 
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId> 
            <version>3.6.4.Final</version> 
        </dependency>       
          <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> 
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId> 
            <version>3.6.4.Final</version> 
        </dependency>
        <!-- 
        <dependency>         
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>         
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>         
            <version>3.6.4.Final</version>     
        </dependency> 
         -->
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>antlr</groupId> 
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId> 
            <version>2.7.6-brew</version> 
        </dependency>            
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId> 
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId> 
            <version>1.6.1-jboss</version> 
        </dependency>                    
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>asm</groupId>  
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>  
            <version>1.4.3</version> 
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>  
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>  
            <version>2.1.1</version>  
        </dependency>     

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.16</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

The error i get is:

```
Missing artifact commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile

Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.6.4.Final:compile

Missing artifact javassist:javassist:jar:3.12.0.GA:compile

Missing artifact org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile

Missing artifact org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile

Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.6.4.Final:compile

Missing artifact commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile

Missing artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.2.0.Final:compile

Missing artifact javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile

Missing artifact antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6-brew:compile

Missing artifact dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1-jboss:compile

Missing artifact xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile

Missing artifact asm:asm:jar:1.4.3:compile

Missing artifact cglib:cglib:jar:2.1.1:compile

---
```

All the above errors go away, if i remove the mysql dependency from the pom.xml file.
I am totally confused why mysql should have dependency on these.

Isn't Maven supposed to resolve these dependencies automatically? Afterall isn't that the whole idea of using Maven.

Experts please guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

You can search for dependencies here:

http://mvnrepository.com

For Maven2 it is:

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/

Hibernate in particular is notoriously difficult for setting up the right dependencies.

See: [How can I use Maven to get the latest Hibernate release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230249/how-can-i-use-maven-to-get-the-latest-hibernate-release)