# Build issue Spring 3 -hibernate 3 Project

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, maven

I have a simple spring3,hibernate 3 project.When am trying to build the project using Maven i got the following errors.

Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/3.3.2.ga/hibernate-entitymanager-3.3.2.ga.jar
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.3.2.ga' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

### Missing:

1) org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.3.2.ga

Anybody know what is the issue, i put anything wrong in my POM.xml.

If i downloaded the jar file, how i added to Maven through my eclipse

Help is highly appreciated,
VKS

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use Maven to get the latest Hibernate release?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230249/how-can-i-use-maven-to-get-the-latest-hibernate-release), also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672352/where-to-get-hibernate-jars-from and probably many others

Comment: >Anybody know what is the issue, i put anything wrong in my POM.xml. If you have doubt that the pom is wrong, you should post ist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [http://mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com/) to search for *hibernate-entitymanager*. Your version looks like this: Do note the upper case in GA ...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: But that's an ancient version. New versions are no longer in maven central and hence no longer found by mvnrepository.com

Comment: Yes, I would advise an upgrade as well, but that was not the question. mvnrepository.com shows versions 3.6.7.Final and 4.0.0.CR4

Comment: @Brambo oh, so they are back in central? Didn't know that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

For hibernate we use following repository:

https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/

Try adding this to your pom:

```
<repository>
     <id>jboss.org</id>
     <name>JBoss Repository</name>
     <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
</repository>
```